# VLOOKUP 2D Formula gives error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've 3 small Datasets.

```
1st has range A123:B126.
2nd dataset range is D123:E126. 
3rd has G123:H126.
Each dataset has Column Heading in row 123, are Project & Code. Each dataset has title in row 122, are HR, IT & SALES.
```

In data range A128:D131 I'm using 2D VLOOKUP to filter related Project Code.

Range A128:D128 has Col headings like,

```
SRNO, PROJECT TITLE, PROJECT, CODE.
```

Range B129:B131 has values HR, IT, SALES. 
Range C129:C131 has BEHAVIOR, CALL, ERP.

Cell D129 had Formula,

```
=VLOOKUP (C129, OFFSET($A$124:$H$126,MATCH(B129, $A$122:$H$122,0),, 2),2,0)
```

NB: It's an Array formula. In D129 it produces correct result but after drag down shows #NA.

Comment: Do you mean "2nd dataset range is D123:E126." rather than D123:D126

Comment: Can you also confirm you pasted the correct vlookup, you have 3 open brackets, but 4 close brackets.

Comment: @Brain,, Yes it's D124:E126 & I've also balanced the formula,, now is,, 

 =VLOOKUP (C129, OFFSET($A$124:$H$126,MATCH(B129, $A$122:$H$122,0),, 2),2,0)

Was trying mistake only. ☺

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your actual requirement is a lot more complicated than this, so hopefully this will help you.

This formula works if you copy it into D129, and you can drag it down. I removed out the offset function as vlookup was finding the cell you wanted.

```
=VLOOKUP(C129,$A$124:$H$126,MATCH(B129,$A$122:$H$122,0)+1,1)
```

[image: Excel screenshot of solution]

Comment: @Brain you have sketched the Scenario very properly,, unfortunately Formula doesn't work, produces error #N/A.

Comment: What version of Excel do you use? Match and vlookup have been around since excel 2003.
Interesting, as it's working on my machine here.

Comment: Bro it's not version's conflict,, but I'm using 2016. Previous versions of my formula was producing 1st correct answer but 2 wrong but yur has zero result.

Comment: Brain finally I've solved the problem. This formula is producing 3 correct results. 

 =IFERROR (INDEX(INDEX($A$124:$H$126,, MATCH(B129, $A$122:$H$122,0)+1), MATCH(C129, INDEX($A$124:$H$126,,MATCH(B129, $A$122:$H$122,0))
,0)), " ") 

NB: It's non array formula. Don't hesitate to vote it. 

Comment: If you have a solution then post it as an answer and accept it. If my solution stops working for me; and I need to solve a problem like this; and your solution helps me - then I will upvote it. Also you know my name is Brian, right :)

Comment: Remember @Brain since I don't have enough credit points to upload the solution as a Answer otherwise I wud have post earlier. ☺ 
Just write me Test Mail at sinha14raj@gmail.com I'll show you the Screen Shots,, that mine final one is WORKING,,.